# WeatherKit extension switch isn't working for specific var

Tags: swift, swiftui, weatherkit

Working on a simple weather app.
I'd like to set a different video for the background for each weather condition (clear, rain, snow, etc...).
Managed to loop-play a video as the background of the View but, for some reason, it does not change based on conditions.
Videos are stored in the Bundle and are called by their string name ("deer", "lake", "snow".

I've made an extension for WeatherConditions:

```swift
extension WeatherCondition {
    var videoBG : String {
        switch self {
            
        case .blizzard:
            return "snow"
        case .blowingDust:
            return "lake"
        case .blowingSnow:
            return "lake"
        case .breezy:
            return "lake"
        case .clear:
            return "deer"
        case .cloudy:
            return "lake"
        case .drizzle:
            return "lake"
        case .flurries:
            return "lake"
        case .foggy:
            return "lake"
        case .freezingDrizzle:
            return "lake"
        case .freezingRain:
            return "lake"
        case .frigid:
            return "lake"
        case .hail:
            return "lake"
        case .haze:
            return "lake"
        case .heavyRain:
            return "lake"
        case .heavySnow:
            return "lake"
        case .hot:
            return "lake"
        case .hurricane:
            return "lake"
        case .isolatedThunderstorms:
            return "lake"
        case .mostlyClear:
            return "deer"
        case .mostlyCloudy:
            return "lake"
        case .partlyCloudy:
            return "lake"
        case .rain:
            return "lake"
        case .scatteredThunderstorms:
            return "lake"
        case .sleet:
            return "lake"
        case .smoky:
            return "lake"
        case .snow:
            return "lake"
        case .strongStorms:
            return "lake"
        case .sunFlurries:
            return "lake"
        case .sunShowers:
            return "lake"
        case .thunderstorms:
            return "deer"
        case .tropicalStorm:
            return "lake"
        case .windy:
            return "lake"
        case .wintryMix:
            return "lake"
        @unknown default:
            return "deer"
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```swift
@MainActor class WeatherKitManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var weather: Weather?
    
    func getWeather() async {
        do {
            weather = try await Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
                return try await WeatherService.shared.weather(for: .init(latitude: 42.34779, longitude: 13.39943))  // Coordinates for SAN PIO just as example coordinates
            }.value
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
    }

    var videoAppBG: String {
        weather?.currentWeather.condition.videoBG ?? "snow"
    }
}
```

and I set it as my video background with:

```
var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            
            BgdFullScreenVideoView(videoName: weatherKitManager.videoAppBG)
                .zIndex(-10)
            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("\(weatherKitManager.temp)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 75))
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .shadow(radius: 8)
                    
                    Text("L'Aquila")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .shadow(radius: 8)
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 80)
            }
            .padding(.leading,25)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                ZStack {
                    Image("logo")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .shadow(radius: 3)
                        .zIndex(10)
                }
                .padding(.top,40)
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        Task {
            await weatherKitManager.getWeather()
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

but I always get "snow" played, no matter the real weather condition.
Used the same way to get temperature, symbolName (etc...) and it works.

In other words, the switch always returns "nill".

Just doesn't for "videoBG".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *the switch always returns "nill"*. No, the switch cannot return `nil` but `weather` can be `nil`.

Comment: Thanks Vadian but is it possible? Why the WeatherCondition vars work fine and just this var "videoBG" is returning nill?

Comment: `videoBG` is non-optional, it cannot be `nil`. But if one of the preceding objects is `nil` it stops the evaluation and returns `nil` immediately. This is called *Optional Chaining*.

Comment: For example if you run `VideoBackground` before running and completing `getWeather`, then you will get snow. So how you are calling them is key. But unfortunately you have chosen to omit that code from your question.

Comment: I've updated my question to show how I set the background in my ContentView. Thanks

Comment: You access `videoAppBG` long before `weather` has been set.

Comment: Thanks HangarRash. How can I access my videoAppBG in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computed property cannot work because it does not refresh the view.

A possible way is to declare another `@Published` property for the `condition` which all related UI elements can retrieve their data from.

But this requires a change in `getWeather` which is too complicated anyway, a detach task is not needed.

And the second task in `.onAppear` is not needed either, replace the modifier with

```
.task {
    await weatherKitManager.getWeather()
}
```

To get rid of the optional I recommend an enum for the state

```
enum LoadingState {
    case idle, loading, success(Weather), failure(Error)
}
```

Then replace the view model with

```
@MainActor class WeatherKitManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var state: LoadingState = .idle
    @Published var condition: WeatherCondition = .clear
    
    func getWeather() async {
        state = .loading
        do {
            let weather = try await WeatherService.shared.weather(for: .init(latitude: 42.34779, longitude: 13.39943))  // Coordinates for SAN PIO just as example coordinates
            state = .success(weather)
            condition = weather.currentWeather.condition
        } catch {
            state = .failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In the view show different views depending on the state for example

```
NavigationView {
    switch weatherKitManager.state {
        case .idle: EmptyView()
        case .loading: ProgressView()
        case .success(let weather):
            ZStack {
                BgdFullScreenVideoView(videoName: weatherKitManager.condition.videoBG)
                    .zIndex(-10)
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(weather.currentWeather.temperature.formatted())
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 75))
                            .fontWeight(.black)
                            .shadow(radius: 8)
                        
                        Text("L'Aquila")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .shadow(radius: 8)
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 80)
                }
                .padding(.leading,25)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            Text(error.localizedDescription).
                .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

Comment: vadian can't say thank you enough...learning a lot!!!